# Split filename into groups

Tags: java, regex

Input:

> "MyPrefix_CH-DE_ProductName.pdf"

Desired output:

> ["MyPrefix", "CH", "DE", "ProductName"]

`CH` is a country code, and it should come from a predefined list, eg. `["CH", "IT", "FR", "GB"]`

Edit: prefix can contain _ and - as well but not CH or DE.

`DE` is a language code, and it should come from a predefined list, eg. `["EN", "IT", "FR", "DE"]`

How do I do that?

I'm looking for a regex based solution here.

Comment: `String#split()` ?

Comment: Use regex to split the filename, filename.split("[_-]")

Comment: Can the prefixes and product names contains underscores or dashes? If not, split over those characters. If they can, use a regex where you represent the possible country code and languages codes using alternations, the underscores around them, capture what precedes in a capturing group that will be your prefix and what's after in a capturing group that will be your product name

Comment: @Aaron yes. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Can any of your pedefined list items (language/country) also occur in your product name, e.g. **IT**ALIANSomething?

Comment: No, fortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume that the extension is always pdf

```
String str = "MyPref_ix__CH-DE_ProductName.pdf";

String regex = "(.*)_(CH|IT|FR|GB)-(EN|IT|FR|DE)_(.*)\\.pdf";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
String[] res = new String[4];

if(matcher.matches()) {
    res[0] = matcher.group(1);
    res[1] = matcher.group(2);
    res[2] = matcher.group(3);
    res[3] = matcher.group(4);
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, but I'd remove the assumption that the extension is always PDF, it doesn't seem to be needed for your code to work and removing it would make your solution work for any extension.

Comment: Here if the extension is not pdf, then the if condition will fail, you can modify the regex to include any extension

Comment: @Aaron is right but I still accept it as the concept is correct and he was slightly faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can use String.split two times so you can first split by '_' to get the CH-DE string and then split by '-' to get the CountryCode and LanguageCode.

Updated after your edit, with input containing '_' and '-':

The following code scans through the input String to find countries matches. I changed the input to "My-Pre_fix_CH-DE_ProductName.pdf"

Check the following code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        String [] countries = {"CH", "IT", "FR", "GB"};
        String input = "My-Pre_fix_CH-DE_ProductName.pdf";
        //First scan to find country position
        int index = -1;
        for (int i=0; i<input.length()-4; i++){
            for (String country:countries){
                String match = "_" + country + "-";
                String toMatch = input.substring(i, match.length()+i);
                if (match.equals(toMatch)){
                    //Found index
                    index=i;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        String prefix = input.substring(0,index);
        String remaining = input.substring(index+1);//remaining is CH-DE_ProductName.pdf
        String [] countryLanguageProductCode = remaining.split("_");
        String country = countryLanguageProductCode[0].split("-")[0];
        String language = countryLanguageProductCode[0].split("-")[1];
        String productName = countryLanguageProductCode[1].split("\\.")[0];
        System.out.println("[\"" + prefix +"\", \"" + country + "\", \"" + language +"\", \"" + productName+"\"]");

    }
```

It outputs:

```
["My-Pre_fix", "CH", "DE", "ProductName"]
```

Comment: See edit: prefix can contain - and _. Sorry for the changing specs :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```
String input = "MyPrefix_CH-DE_ProductName.pdf";

String[] segments = input.split("_");


String prefix = segments[0];
String countryCode = segments[1].split("-")[0];
String languageCode = segments[1].split("-")[1];
String fileName = segments[2].substring(0, segments[2].length() - 4);

System.out.println("prefix " + prefix);
System.out.println("countryCode " + countryCode);
System.out.println("languageCode " + languageCode);
System.out.println("fileName " + fileName);
```

Comment: See edit: prefix can contain - and _. Sorry for the changing specs :)

Answer (score 0):

this code does the split and create an object using the returned result, more OOP.

```
package com.local;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        List<String> countries = Arrays.asList("CH", "IT", "FR", "GB");
        List<String> languages  = Arrays.asList("EN", "IT", "FR", "DE");
        String filename = "MyPrefix_CH-DE_ProductName.pdf";
        //Remove prefix
        filename = filename.split("\\.")[0];
        List<String> result = Arrays.asList(filename.split("[_\\-]"));

        FileNameSplitResult resultOne = new FileNameSplitResult(result.get(0), result.get(1), result.get(2), result.get(3));

        System.out.println(resultOne);
    }

    static class FileNameSplitResult{
        String prefix;
        String country;
        String language;
        String productName;

        public FileNameSplitResult(String prefix, String country, String language, String productName) {
            this.prefix = prefix;
            this.country = country;
            this.language = language;
            this.productName = productName;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "FileNameSplitResult{" +
                    "prefix='" + prefix + '\'' +
                    ", country='" + country + '\'' +
                    ", language='" + language + '\'' +
                    ", productName='" + productName + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }
}
```

Result of execution:

```
FileNameSplitResult{prefix='MyPrefix', country='CH', language='DE', productName='ProductName'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex :

```
^(.*?)_(CH|IT|FR|GB)-(EN|IT|FR|DE)_(.*)$
```

Java code :

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(.*?)_(CH|IT|FR|GB)-(EN|IT|FR|DE)_(.*)$");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
if (m.matches()) {
    String[] result = { m.group(1), m.group(2), m.group(3), m.group(4) };
}
```

You can [try it here](https://ideone.com/CjSCIz).

Note that it would still fail if the prefix could contain a substring like `_CH-EN_`, and I don't think there's much than can be done about it beside sanitize the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

One more alternative, which is pretty much the same as @billal GHILAS and @Aaron answers but using named groups. I find it handy for myself or for others who after a while look at my code immediately see what my regex does. The named groups make it easier.

```
String str = "My_Prefix_CH-DE_ProductName.pdf";
Pattern filePattern = Pattern.compile("(?<prefix>\\w+)_"
                                      + "(?<country>CH|IT|FR|GB)-" 
                                      + "(?<language>EN|IT|FR|DE)_" 
                                      + "(?<product>\\w+)\\.");
Matcher file = filePattern.matcher(str);
file.find();
System.out.println("Prefix: " + file.group("prefix"));
System.out.println("Country: " + file.group("country"));
System.out.println("Language: " + file.group("language"));
System.out.println("Product: " + file.group("product"));
```